# How to make searchbar input search for a string with both big letters and small letters without changing the strings text

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a text that I want to remain the same, but via a searchbar be able to find the words even if it is a big Letter or a small letter.

I currently have it ToLower on both the string with the value I am searching on (theDescription, a string) and my searchbar textinput ToLower but the problem is that I want the text to remain the same with Big letters and small etc not like it is now that everything is small (it works) but the letters should remain the same.

so, how can I adjust my current "solution" to make the text inside my string theDescription not change the text to all lower cases but have it the same way but still be able to search words even if it is big letter or small letter.

```
public StartPage ()
    {
        searchBar.TextChanged += (sender2, e2) => FilterPins(searchBar.Text.ToLower());

        searchBar.SearchButtonPressed += (sender2, e2) => FilterPins(searchBar.Text.ToLower());

    }
```

And this is the value that I am searching through via a filter.

```
pin.Address = theDescription.ToLower();
```

My filter function:

```
private  async void FilterPins (string filter)
    {
        map.Pins.Clear ();

        foreach(Pin p in myPins) {
            if (p.Address.Contains(filter)) {

                map.Pins.Add (p);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the casing of the text when you search ONLY (remove all the other ToLower() you currently have)

```
// force the search text and the value to be searched into the same case
if (p.Address.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())) {
```

Incidentally, the term for what you want is "case insensitive" (you don't care if the case matches).  If you do care, the term is "case sensitive".

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks alot. Works perfectly